# Is it possible to get index of the slave process at the runtime?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Suppose I run pm2 in cluster mode `pm2 start app.js -i 4`, Is it possible to get information about current number in the instances pool **inside** the app.js.

I mean in the `app-0` it would be `0`, in the `app-1` it would be `1`, etc. I need to get this number at runtime.

I didn't find any references in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found!

```
process.env.pm_id
```

Thanks to this [guy](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#comment-2668454965)